# Tool to reuse old laptop screen as a monitor

Tags: monitors

My old laptop is now out of service, but it had a very nice FHD screen that works with [this cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B072K4MKG4), while I'm missing a second monitor for myself.

I've seen [this post](https://www.instructables.com/id/Turn-a-dead-laptop-into-a-monitor-with-Plexiglas-s/) and was wondering if there was any off-the shelf tool that would allow me to use the screen as a second monitor, even if without the stand at first.

Anything that accepts HDMI or display port as input would be great. Something that ships internationally would be nice too.

Comment: What laptop is it, and where were you looking for shipping to?

Comment: It's a Dell Inspiron, I need the part shipped to Brazil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to find out what that panel actually is. Let's try searching for Inspiron 7520 LCD replacement panel: https://www.google.com/search?q=dell+inspiron+7520+lcd+replacement+panel this is not fruitful immediately but it does lead to https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Dell-Inspiron-15r-7520-SE-screen-model-number/td-p/4304809 tells us the screen Dell part number is DC9YJ. Progress!

Feeding that into Google https://www.google.com/search?q=dc9yj we quickly find (it's in the result list, even) the panel is compatible with LP156WFC(TL)(B1). (A quick countercheck shows it's [resolution](https://www.google.com/search?q=LP156WFC+resolution&oq=LP156WFC+resolution&aqs=chrome..69i57.1798j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is indeed FHD)

Our next and last search is for the driver board for that: https://www.google.com/search?q=LP156WFC(TL)(B1)+driver+board which leads us to

https://www.ebay.com/itm/Kit-for-LP156WFC-TL-B1-LED-LCD-Controller-Driver-Board-HDMI-DVI-VGA-/122509319792

which is what you are looking for I believe.

Comment: The link you provided is nice, thanks. "Driver board" was the key word I was missing =) Would be nice if there were something with better packaging. Looking at [this link](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33012324329.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.574562eebaWlW1&algo_pvid=d89a5203-36d2-4ce5-ac49-517c882fa285&algo_expid=d89a5203-36d2-4ce5-ac49-517c882fa285-0&btsid=b60d760d-2bc4-42db-a2c8-f12a79d003fa&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_6,searchweb201603_53) the seller also provides [plastic cases](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000010610937.html?spm=a2g0o.detail.1000023.3.74a0fa205cUgqi)